# Pubnub Not Working On Google App Engine (GAE)

Tags: java, mysql, json, google-app-engine, pubnub

I am creating a web application on Google App Engine that allows me to subscribe to a Pubnub channel, receiving messages and store those messages to database. I have upload the code to Google App Engine but it seems not working as I check on the GAE log, it is not updating. The database also not updating after I try on the debug console at Pubnub website. I pretty sure my channel name, subscribe and publish key are correct. I obtain the code from [Pubnub Github Example](https://github.com/pubnub/java/blob/GAE_3.3/java/3.3/src/com/pubnub/examples/PubnubExample.java). Hope all users here can help me on finding and pointing out the problem. I am still new on Pubnub and ready for any advice. Thank you very much.

My Code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.pubnub.api.Callback;
import com.pubnub.api.Pubnub;
import com.pubnub.api.PubnubException;
import com.yihwei95.model.appdata.AppData;

class Receiver implements Callback {
    public boolean successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
        final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver";
        final String DB_URL = "jdbc:google:mysql"
                                    + "://****"
                                    + ":asia-northeast1"
                                    + ":****/****?user=****";   

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement prst = null;

        try {
            if (message instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) message;
                AppData ad = new AppData();
                String email = obj.getString("email");
                ad.setEmail(email);
                String password = obj.getString("password");
                ad.setPassword(password);
                String token = obj.getString("token");
                ad.setToken(token);

                Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
                String SQL = "INSERT INTO ****"
                            + "(email, password, token)"
                            + "VALUES(?, ? ,?)";
                prst = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
                prst.setString(1, ad.getEmail());
                prst.setString(2, ad.getPassword());
                prst.setString(3, ad.getToken());
                prst.executeUpdate();
                prst.close();
                conn.close();
                //@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                //Iterator keys = obj.keys();
                //while (keys.hasNext()) {
                    //System.out.print(obj.get(keys.next().toString())
                            //+ " ");
                //}
                //System.out.println();
            } 
            else if (message instanceof String) {
                String obj = (String) message;
                //System.out.print(obj + " ");
                //System.out.println();
            } 
            else if (message instanceof JSONArray) {
                JSONArray obj = (JSONArray) message;
                //System.out.print(obj.toString() + " ");
                //System.out.println();
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Continue Listening?
        return true;
    }

    public void errorCallback(String channel, Object message) {
        //System.err.println("Channel:" + channel + "-"
                //+ message.toString());

    }

    public void connectCallback(String channel) {
        //System.out.println("Connected to channel :" + channel);
        //System.out.println("Waiting for message ...");
    }

    public void reconnectCallback(String channel) {
        //System.out.println("Reconnected to channel :" + channel);
    }

    public void disconnectCallback(String channel) {
        //System.out.println("Disconnected to channel :" + channel);
    }
}

public class Testing{
    static String subscribeKey = "****";
    static String publishKey = "****";
    static String channel = "****";
    static Pubnub pubnub = null;

    public Testing(){
        pubnub = new Pubnub(publishKey, subscribeKey);
        postAppData();
    }

    private static void postAppData(){
        try{
            pubnub.subscribe(channel, new Receiver());
        }
        catch(PubnubException pubnube){
            pubnube.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }   
    }
}
```

JAR Used

[image: JAR Used]

Or should I modify my Web.XML file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestingGCP</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.yihwei95.TestingGCPServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestingGCP</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/testinggcp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: @CraigConover Hi. Thanks for the comment. I see that the v3 is EOL'ed, I will start using the v4 SDK. I wish to ask that it is possible for me to host the app at Amazon Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: @CraigConover Hi. Craig. Thanks for your detailed explanation. Appreciate it very much.

Comment: Posted my comments as official answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## GAE and Long Running Operations/Connection

GAE does not allow you to subscribe because it is a long running connection. And the PubNub Java SDK v3 is EOL'ed so would recommend using v4 SDK (still won't solve the GAE/subscribe issue). Should work on other app hosts such as Heroku and the like.

Not familiar with beanstalk specifics but should work as long as it allows your connection to stay open. I did read a quick blurb about using beanstalk to deploy web applications but you would not use PubNub subscribe in the context of a web request because web requests are short lived. You might do a publish within a web request but not subscribe. Subscribe would likely be performed on your client side app (browser - using JavaScript SDK).

### UPDATE

When using the [PubNub Java v4 SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java-se-java/pubnub-java-sdk) inside GAE, be sure to enable it in the PNConfiguration instance. Full details are provided in the [Does the Java SDK run on Google App Engine? KB article](https://support.pubnub.com/support/solutions/articles/14000043756-does-the-java-sdk-run-on-google-app-engine-).